# how to create a custom url using html5

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder how to create some kind of custom url in html5

Lets say I have a homepage called test.com and books on a page.
Then depending on what url the user goes to the content of a specific book shows.
For instance: test.com/book/16156161 where 16156161 is what defines which book to show, because onload the id 16156161 from url will be used to get the correct book.

Now I could have this page test.com/book but I don't know how to let it accept a string at the end of the url withut getting a 404.

How can this be done using html/javascript ?

Any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It can't be done with html/javascript only, your webserver is handling incoming requests, it should serve same html file for all those requests and only then you can handle your different URLs with javascript.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you

Comment: @Walk You could somewhat fake it with a front end router like with Angular's router, but it would still require some server configuration.  I would suggest OP pick a framework (like Angular, React, or Vue), do some research on that framework's routing capabilities (Like reviewing https://angular.io/guide/router), make an attempt, and come back.

Comment: @zero298 absolutely, that's what I meant by handling URLs with javascript, but first your webserver should serve that javascript somehow, so you have to configure it, for example here is configruation of Nginx to server same file (index.html) for most requests: https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/nginx.html , it doesn't by default and will return 404 otherwise.

Comment: Customize 404 page by obtaining the referred uri then redirecting to each book page corresponding to the referrer uri.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
    
   var my_url_list = [12,42]; // your ids
    
   $.each(my_url_list, function( index, value ) {
    
     var href =   '<a href="https://www.book.com'+value+'">book'+value+' </a> </br>';
         
        $("#links").append(href);
  });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with node, using the `fs`module you could do this, assuming you have an array of book urls named `books`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/books/" + books[i], fileContent, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("File successfully saved");
  });
}
```